# Get view by tag from React Native to Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I need to get a view by tagId from React Native to Objective C with native modules.
I've tried:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(initVideoContainer:(int)tagId) {

    [self.bridge.uiManager addUIBlock:^(RCTUIManager *uiManager, NSDictionary<NSNumber *, UIView *> *viewRegistry) {
        UIView *view = viewRegistry[[NSNumber numberWithInt:tagId]];
        if (![view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            RCTLog(@"expecting UIView, got: %@", view);
        }
        else {

        }
    }];
}
```

But, I get an error:

> -[RNNativePlayerAdapter bridge]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000014292a0' was thrown while invoking initVideoContainer
>   on target RNNativePlayerAdapter with params (
>       3 )

How can I get the view with tagID that we have on JS with RCTUIManager? This code is from Xcode, Objective C and the view is on JS files.

Thanks,
Claudiu

Comment: Error description is pretty clear - error is thrown at `self.bridge` because `self` is apparently `RNNativePlayerAdapter` and that class doesn't have a property called `bridge` which you are trying to access. What are you trying to do with `self.bridge`? What is that supposed to return?

Comment: I am trying to use uiManager, because I've read that with uiManager you can access the view from JS.

Comment: I need the view from JS to use on iOS. I am new to React Native.

Comment: initVideoContainer is a method that is called from JS files. Is there another method to get the view?

Comment: I works by adding this code:

@synthesize bridge = _bridge;

- (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
{
    return self.bridge.uiManager.methodQueue;
}